# "this" stops working when argument passed to function

Tags: javascript, event-handling, this

I have two javascript functions, one which attaches an eventhandler to an entire class of elements and the other which is called when the event handler is activated:

```
function attachDefinition(obj) {
    var classArr = document.getElementsByClassName("flashcards");
    for (let i = 0, len = classArr.length; i < len; i++) {
        classArr[i].addEventListener('click', cardClicked);
    }
}

function cardClicked(obj) {
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(obj);
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'https://www.wordnik.com/img/wordnik_badge_a2.png';
    document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById(this.id).appendChild(img);
}
```

The above function runs without error on click. `this.id` logged to the console displays the id of the `div` element being clicked and obj logs the global object.

This is fine however I need to pass in an object created in a different function in the program. The above code only needs the obj argument added to `addEventListener` call but when I do that everything falls apart. This code:

```
function attachDefinition(obj) {
    var classArr = document.getElementsByClassName("flashcards");
    for (let i = 0, len = classArr.length; i < len; i++) {
        classArr[i].addEventListener('click', cardClicked(obj)); //only thing I've changed!
    }
}

function cardClicked(obj) {
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(obj);
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'https://www.wordnik.com/img/wordnik_badge_a2.png';
    document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById(this.id).appendChild(img);
}
```

Now successfully console logs the passed in object but the line logging `this.id` is now undefined and I get "Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference"  on the innerHTML line.

I'm struggling to understand why passing in an argument would change `this` and how I can go about fixing it.

Comment: `cardClicked(obj)` needs to return a function

Comment: `classArr[i].addEventListener('click', cardClicked(obj);` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that your

```
classArr[i].addEventListener('click', cardClicked(obj);
```

is really

```
classArr[i].addEventListener('click', cardClicked(obj));
// Note ---------------------------------------------^
```

that's **calling** `cardClicked` and passing its return value into `addEventListener`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

But `addEventListener` expects a function in the second argument, and `cardClicked` doesn't *return* a function.

Instead, since you're relying on `this` referring to the clicked element inside `cardClicked`, you either need:

```
classArr[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    cardClicked.call(this, obj);
});
```

or

```
classArr[i].addEventListener('click', cardClicked.bind(classArr[i], obj));
```

The first works by responding to a click by calling `cardClicked` such that the `this` it sees is the same as the `this` the anonymous function receives.

The second works by using `Function#bind` to create a new function that, when called, will call `cardClicked` with `this` set to the avlue of `classArr[i]` and its first argument set to `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `classArr[i].addEventListener('click', cardClicked(obj);` to this instead:

```
classArr[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    cardClicked(obj);
});
```

First off, you're missing a `)` in the original. Additionally, you need to create an anonymous function when passing parameters in setInterval, otherwise the function in question will execute immediately upon reading.

Comment: Yes, but what's the problem? Why does this fix it?

Comment: Ideally, make the answer complete *before* posting it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Quite honestly, I'm not exactly sure of why this works. I just wanted to spare OP the few minutes it takes while I go look up the true reasoning behind it, and give him an answer. My plan was to come back and edit it the entire time, but I'd rather not hold up answering for that.

Comment: Actually, the above *doesn't* work. The `this` in `cardClicked` will be wrong, so `this.id` won't have the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

when you assign a function to an event as action on trigger then the function's `this` would point to element which event fire on. your first implementation uses this advantage and then you can use `this` in your function to refer to related element.

But the problem in second implementation is that the function is called instead of assignment.

If you want to send additional data to you callback you can use function `call` or `apply`:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var obj = { addtional: 'data' };
    myCallback.call(this, obj);
})

function myCallback (obj){
    console.log(this.id, obj);
}
```

#### [function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> The call() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.

#### [function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

> The apply() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).